# Como hacer búsqueda de datos en dos tablas en phalcon

Tags: phalcon

Alguien me podría explicar cómo buscar datos en dos tablas Phalcon:

Tengo esta consulta:

```
$Q = $this->request->getPost("data");
$phql = 'SELECT b.idbank,b.name,m.description,m.date
         FROM bank b
         inner join movement m on b.idbank=m.idbank
         WHERE b.estado = 1 and b.name like "%'.$Q.'%"  or m.description like "%'.$Q.'%" 
         Order by b.idbank desc
         ';

$bank = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

Habría alguna manera de hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$Q = $this->request->getPost("data");
$bank = Bank::find(
[
        "name like '%:dato:%'",
        "bind" => [
            "dato" => $Q
        ]
    ]
);

$mov = $bank->getmovement(
    [
        "description like '%:dato:%'",
        "bind" => [
            "dato" => $Q
        ]
    ]
);

$bank = $mov->bank;
```

En realidad no sé cómo hacerlo.

no está funcionando lo que hice, todo esta mal.

Un poco de ayuda sería importante para mí. Gracias.

Comment: La primera consulta arroja algo? La segunda, si ejecutas sólo Bank::find, y en vez de :dato: pones :dato, arroja algo?

Comment: La primera consulta funciona normal, porque es un Select normal a puro código sql, el problema es que no se como hacer que me muestren los datos de la segunda forma. No sé como como mostrar los parametros de ambas tablas "b.idbank, b.name, m.description, m.date" pero dependiendo de las condiciones del WHERE. La segunda consulta no arroja nada esta mal, en realidad nose como hacerla.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es una respuesta completa y algún voto negativo me llevaré, pero los comentarios no sirven para mostrar bien el código.

En tu segundo ejemplo, la consulta a Bank debiera tener la forma:

```
$bank = Bank::find([
    'conditions' => 'name LIKE :dato:',
    'bind' => ['dato' => '%' . $Q . '%']
]);

// dumpear el resultado
var_dump($bank);
```

Respecto a la consulta de movimientos, pienso que no te sirve ejecutar una consulta sobre `$bank->getmovement`, porque no es un repositorio sino una colección de resultados. Los movimientos de un banco cuyo nombre calza con $Q.

La consulta de movimientos debiera tener la forma

```
$mov = Movement::find([
    'conditions' => 'description LIKE :dato:',
    'bind' => ['dato' => '%' . $Q . '%']
]);

// dumpear el resultado
var_dump($mov);
```

Al final de esto tendrías el banco cuyo nombre calza con $Q y todos sus movimientos, y tendrías los movimientos cuya descripción calza con $Q y sus respectivos bancos.

Si todo eso funciona, te quedaría un último paso que es hacer un merge de esas entidades convertidas en arrays.

Comment: Solo me faltaría hacer esto: $bank->merge($mov);??

Comment: Eso depende del ORM de phalcon, que no lo conozco.